# How to access Backoffice in Junit Tenant

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

We can access HMC in JUnit tenant by hitting the below URL

```
https://localhost:9002/hmc_junit/hybris
```

which is defined in `tenant_junit.properties` like this `hmc.webroot=/hmc_junit`

But I havn't seen anywhere URL to access Backoffice in JUnit Tenant.

Can anybody help me please to access Backoffice in JUnit Tenant ?

Comment: Remember to mark it as answered if it's the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was looking for it everywhere as well, couldn't find any documentation in the wiki... It doesn't seem to be officially supported but here is what I found.

Under Hybris 6.3 there is no junit context path for the backoffice application. Here is how you could add one :

- Create a file named : **local_tenant_junit.properties** under your configuration folder, it should contain :

  backoffice.webroot=/backoffice_junit
- Create a file for customization inside your config folder *customize/ext-backoffice/backoffice/web/webroot/WEB-INF/backoffice-spring-filter.xml*. Copy the content of the original file and update the *backofficeFilterChain* bean. We want to use the *dynamicTenantActivationFilter* instead of the *tenantActivationFilter*) :

  ```
  <bean id="backofficeFilterChain" class="de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.PlatformFilterChain">
  <constructor-arg>
      <list>
          <ref bean="log4jFilter"/>
          <ref bean="dynamicTenantActivationFilter"/>
          <ref bean="backofficeRedirectFilter"/>
          <ref bean="sessionFilter"/>
          <ref bean="backofficeDataSourceSwitchingFilter"/>
          <ref bean="backofficeCatalogVersionActivationFilter"/>
          <ref bean="backofficeContextClassloaderFilter"/>
          <ref bean="backofficeSecureMediaFilter" />
      </list>
  </constructor-arg>
  ```
- Execute *ant clean all customize*
- Check that in *bin/platform/tomcat/conf/server.xml* you now have a new context *backoffice_junit*
- Start your server, you can now access the backoffice application for master and junit tenant

Answer (score 1):

For Hybris 6.7, to me the following steps were sufficient:

- in config/local_tenant_junit.properties , add

  ```
  backoffice.webroot=/backoffice_junit
  ```
- ant server

  this puts the endpoint into ${tomcat.webapps} in server.xml template resulting in:

  ```
  <Context path="/backoffice_junit"...
  ```

  being added to your bin/platform/tomcat/conf/server.xml

Then when you open https://localhost:9002/backoffice_junit , the DataSourceSwitchingFilter gets current tenant from a ThreadLocal and activates its dataSource.

Answer (score 0):

Config values inside the junit local properties that worked for me:

```
backoffice.library.home=${data.home}/junit
backoffice.webroot=/junit_backoffice
```

For more info see:
https://help.sap.com/viewer/5c9ea0c629214e42b727bf08800d8dfa/1811/en-US/c7e1bf2832414c8ea15c001d5cf1defd.html