# Error on multi-tenant hybris backoofice start-up

Tags: multi-tenant, sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

I have setup a slave tenant on a Hybris 1811 installation, but I cannot get the backoffice to work for the slave tenant (foo). The error that I get in browser is: Server Error.

I have followed the instructions from here: [How to access Backoffice in Junit Tenant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44630298/how-to-access-backoffice-in-junit-tenant), but I cannot get it to work.

tenant_foo.properties

```
db.tableprefix=foo_
cronjob.timertask.loadonstartup=false
tenant.restart.on.connection.error=false
db.factory=de.hybris.platform.jdbcwrapper.JUnitDataSourceFactory
db.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:foo
db.driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
db.username=foo
db.password=bar
hac.webroot=/hac_foo
```

local_tenant_foo.properties

```
backoffice.webroot=/backoffice_foo
```

I have checked the Hybris logs and found this error:

```
ERROR [localhost-startStop-3] (foo) [ContextLoader] Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValidationException: java.io.IOException: Unable to remove a module library: E:\hybris-1811\data\backoffice\widgetlib\deployed\voucherbackoffice.jar; nested exception is com.hybris.cockpitng.core.CockpitApplicationException: java.io.IOException: Unable to remove a module library: E:\hybris-1811\data\backoffice\widgetlib\deployed\voucherbackoffice.jar
        at com.hybris.backoffice.BackofficeApplicationContext.prepareRefresh(BackofficeApplicationContext.java:106) ~[classes/:?]
```

HAC works fine for both tenants (master and foo), but backoffice only works for the master tenant. Also, if I navigate to HAC->tenants-> foo -> view -> configured extension, I can see that for extensions acceleratorservices and admincockpit, under the WebContext column it displays "Missing configuration for this context in current tenant".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add backoffice library home for each tenant:

```
backoffice.library.home=${data.home}/foo
```

(foo is the tenant id). There is also some documentation about it in the help [here](https://help.sap.com/viewer/5c9ea0c629214e42b727bf08800d8dfa/1811/en-US/c7e1bf2832414c8ea15c001d5cf1defd.html?q=backoffice%20multi%20tenant).

I hope it helps!